# Rectangle wont appear in form box

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# and i was trying to get a rectangle to appear in a forms box(Probably not the correct name) but each time time i run the code the form just appears to be empty no matter what i do. The code im using is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MovingObject
{
    public partial class ObjectMove : Form
    {
        public ObjectMove() => InitializeComponent();


        public void DrawRectangleRectangle(PaintEventArgs e)
        {


            Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);


            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200);


            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, rect);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `DrawRectangleRectangle` called? Is it hooked up to an event in the designer file? If so, show that code, too.

Answer (score 0):

As @mmathis has alluded in the comments, if your method isn't invoked then you won't see the rectangle.

As your method requires a `PaintEventArgs` parameter, a simple way to invoke it is by overriding one of the `OnPaint` eventhandlers and adding a call to the method.

Here's a working example which overrides `OnPaint'

```
public partial class ObjectMove : Form
{
    public ObjectMove() => InitializeComponent();

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        DrawRectangleRectangle(e);
    }

    private void DrawRectangleRectangle(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, rect);
    }
}
```